# Add different span class to wp nav menu

Tags: menus

Here is my html for the menu:

```
<div id="main-menu-container">
                <ul id="main-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-briefcase"></span>Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-cog"></span>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-download"></span>Freebies</a></li>      
                <li><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-user"></span>About</a></li>                 
                </ul>
            </div>
```

& the wp code:

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( 
array(
 'theme_location' => 'primary',
'container_id' => 'main-menu-container',
'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
) 
); 
?>
```

As you can see, the problem is I have different span class added to each list item. & I can not use `link_before` & `link_after`. I have no idea how to add them in `wp_nav_menu`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add different classes to each menu, you can do that by JS. In JS just add a array, where you should save corresponding menu and it's class. and run a each loop to add classes to menu.